# How to read request body dynamic attributes in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am very new to express and have a small question. Actually I am a SAP developer, but learning express.

I have few form input text elements in JADE which are dynamically generated. The form elements which are generated dynamically are called optiondes1, optiondes2, optiondes3 and so on. Now, when I post the request, I can see in req.body all those input text values.

How to extract or read the dynamic text elements value from the request body (req.body). I am using body parser. Similarly, I also want to read the dynamic files elements named file1, file2, and so on from the req.files. Please advice.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numofoptions; i++){

    var optcount = i + 1;
    optdes = ('req.body.' + 'optiondes' + optcount);
    // This prints req.body.optiondes1 as string, but I need the value of req.body.optiondes1
    console.log(optdes); 

    optfile = 'file' + optcount;
    origFileName = ('req.files.' + optfile + '.originalFilename');
    console.log(origFileName);
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
optdes = req.body['optiondes' + optcount]
```

For more examples, search for things like: [Converting string to variable name. (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995303/converting-string-to-variable-name-javascript)