# Creating object by using string as a name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My function gets model name as string, I need to create new instance of object based on its name.

ex.:

```
    modelName = 'MockA';
    model = new modelName();
```

this is ofcourse not working. in php i would use

```
    model = new $$modelName
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Something like [*Converting string to variable name*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995303/converting-string-to-variable-name-javascript) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `MockA` is in global scope you can use:

```
var model = new window[modelName]();
```

if not then you should reconsider the way you store your models, eg. with an object of models:

```
var my_models = {
   MockA: function() {},
   MockB: function() {}
}
```

and to access

```
var MockA = my_models.MockA;
// or
var model_name = 'MockA';
var MockA = my_models[model_name];
```

Comment: but what if its not in global scope?

Comment: @irvgk If it's not attached on any object, then you are screwed.

Comment: anctualy is an mongoose model exported as odule.exports = mongoose.model('Client', new Schema({

Comment: For a more compatible solution in global scope, instead of *window*, consider `var global = this; var model = new global[modelName]()`. But the object solution is far better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `object factory` or `bracket notation`.

Sample of code:

```js
// First example: Use a Factory
var MockA = function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
      console.log('Hi from MockA ');
    };
  },
  MockB = function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
      console.log('Hi from MockB ');
    }
  },
  factory = function(type) {
    var obj;
    switch (type) {
      case 'MockA':
        obj = new MockA();
        break;
      case 'MockB':
        obj = new MockB();
        break;
    }
    return obj;
  }

var objA = factory('MockA');
objA.sayHello();
var objB = factory('MockB');
objB.sayHello();

// Second example: Using bracket notation
var models = {
  BaseMockA: {
    sayHello: function() {
      console.log('Hi from BaseMockA ');
    }
  },
  BaseMockB: {
    sayHello: function() {
      console.log('Hi from BaseMockB ');
    }
  }
};
var baseObjA = Object.create(models['BaseMockA']);
baseObjA.sayHello();
var baseObjB = Object.create(models['BaseMockB']);
baseObjB.sayHello();
```

Comment: You are aware that *both* `MockA` and `MockB` will be created *each* time `Factory` is called, this is hugely ineffective.

Comment: @andrc, thanks for your comment. Please look at my edit.